# Twitter4j TwitterFactory class not found exception

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to setup a twitter bot using twitter4j. When I try to run the following code:

```
package app;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.Twitter;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterFactory
        at app.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.TwitterFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

The code compiles, and I am including the twitter4j-core jar file in my classpath when I complile. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you include the twitter4j-core jar file in your classpath **when you run this program**?

Comment: I ran it with it in the classpath and it's now working, thanks so much! Do you always need to include jar files in the classpath when running or only sometimes?

Comment: Yes. jar files are always needed when running.